# how to change active class when clicking a link javascript, codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I know this is a very common question, I tried to change active class link with the help of javascript, css but I am not able to figure out how to do it. Need some help here...

**view: Navbar header.php**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav1" >
        <li class="active">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>register'> Register</a>
        </li>
        <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) : ?>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="link" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Profile<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile/index'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> </span> About me</a></li>
                <li><a href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile/getskill'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> </span> Skills</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascrpit: file active.js** loaded in footer of my page

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav1 a').filter(function(){
        return this.href==location.href}).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
    // $('#nav1 a').click(function(){
    //  $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')    
    // })
})
```

**css:**

```
ul #nav1 a { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: have you tried using `$this->uri->segment();`?

Comment: I have tried that also, but I think i am doing some mistake over there... @boang3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a suggestion not solution

```
$class = $this->router->fetch_class();
 $method = $this->router->fetch_method();
```

these will give you class name n the method so you can you them like

```
    <li class="active">
  <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" <?php if ($method == "view" && $class == "pages") {
   echo 'class="active"';
} ?>>Home</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about" <?php if ($method == "index" && $class == "profile") {
   echo 'class="active"';
} ?>>About</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>register' <?php if ($method == "index" && $class == "register") {
   echo 'class="active"';
} ?>> Register</a>
</li>
```

Remember i assumed `home` is your controller name

Comment: where to write this code  :                                                                     
 $class = $this->router->fetch_class();
 $method = $this->router->fetch_method(); @VijaySharma

Comment: @SohailShaikh above the links or top of the page

Comment: yes , added to the top of the page still not working @VijaySharma

Comment: @SohailShaikh can you tell me `controller` in which `register` is present, and for `about` and `home` also so i can edit my answer.

Comment: @SohailShaikh one thing did you auto load the `url` helper in project?

Comment: @SohailShaikh above the links or top of the page

Comment: register is in register controller method index, about is in pages(controller) and (method) is view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154951/discussion-between-sohail-shaikh-and-vijay-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remembered using this framework, you don't need javascript just CSS which is the `active` class. You just need to use `$this->uri->segment();`.

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav1" >
            <li <?php if($this->uri->segment(1) == "/"){echo 'class="active"';}?>>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li <?php if($this->uri->segment(1) == "about"){echo 'class="active"';}?>>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li <?php if($this->uri->segment(1) == "register"){echo 'class="active"';}?>>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/register">Register</a>
            </li>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of navigation items you can do it this way (very simplified)...

example:-

```
<ul>
  <li<?= if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/about' ): ?> id="active"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```